# Creating a vector of strings using the new std::fs::File

Tags: string, performance, vector, rust

Porting my code from old_io to the new std::io

```
let path = Path::new("src/wordslist/english.txt");
let display = path.display();
let mut file = match File::open(&path) {
    // The `desc` field of `IoError` is a string that describes the error
    Err(why) => panic!("couldn't open {}: {}", display,
                                               Error::description(&why)),
    Ok(file) => file,
};

let mut s = String::new();
match file.read_to_string(&mut s) {
    Err(why) => panic!("couldn't read {}: {}", display,
                                               Error::description(&why)),
    Ok(s) => s,
};

let words: Vec<_> = s.words().collect();
```

So this works but requires me to have a mutable string s to read the file contents, and then use words().collect() to gather into into a vector,

Is there a way to read the contents of a file to a vector using something like words() WITHOUT reading it to the mutable buffer string first? My thought is that this would be more performant in situations where the collect() call might happen at a later point, or after a words().map(something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach has a problem. `.words()` operates on an `&str` (string slice) which needs a parent `String` to refer to. Your example works fine because the `Vec` produced by `s.words().collect()` resides in the same scope as `s`, so it won't outlive the source string. But if you want to move it somewhere else, you'll need to end up with a `Vec<String>` instead of a `Vec<&str>`, which I'm assuming you already want if you're concerned about intermediate buffers.

You do have some options. Here's two that I can think of.

You can iterate over the characters of the file and split on whitespace:

```
// `.peekable()` gives us `.is_empty()` for an `Iterator`
// `.chars()` yields a `Result<char, CharsError>` which needs to be dealt with
let mut chars = file.chars().map(Result::unwrap).peekable();
let mut words: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

while !chars.is_empty() {
    // This needs a type hint because it can't rely on info 
    // from the following `if` block
    let word: String = chars.take_while(|ch| !ch.is_whitespace()).collect();

    // We'll have an empty string if there's more than one 
    // whitespace character between words 
    // (more than one because the first is eaten 
    // by the last iteration of `.take_while()`)
    if !word.is_empty() {
        words.push(word);
    }
}
```

You can wrap the `File` object in a [`std::io::BufReader`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) and read it line-by-line with the `.lines()` iterator:

```
let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
let mut words = Vec::new();

// `.lines()` yields `Result<String, io::Error>` so we have to handle that.
// (it will not yield an EOF error, this is for abnormal errors during reading)
for line in reader.lines().map(Result::unwrap) {
    words.extend(line.words().map(String::from_str));        
}

// Or alternately (this may not work due to lifetime errors in `flat_map()`
let words: Vec<_> = reader.lines().map(Result::unwrap)
    .flat_map(|line| line.words().map(String::from_str))
    .collect();
```

It's up to you to decide which of the two solutions you prefer. The former is probably more efficient but maybe less intuitive. The latter is easier to read, especially the `for`-loop version, but allocates intermediate buffers.

Comment: the old_io way allowed me to read the file to a string without mutability:

    let word_backing: String = match file.read_to_string() {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't read {}: {}", display, why.desc),
        Ok(string) => string,
    };
    let words: Vec<_> = word_backing.words().collect();

Is there no way to do that with the new std::io

Comment: The only difference between `read_to_string()` in `old_io` and `read_to_string()` in the new `io` is that you're required to allocate the string yourself and pass it as `&mut String`. This provides a better representation for intermediate state as the method can return an error but you can still use what it's read up to that point, instead of losing everything.

Comment: @AustinB it also allows you to avoid extraneous allocation, if you happen to already have an allocated string or you want to read from multiple sources into one string.